# What is the advantage of using the class Unsafe to write atomics over synchronize blocks?

Tags: java, atomic, unsafe

why java Atomics uses sun Unsafe class rather than using synchronize block/volatile?

Answer (score 4):

synchronization is much more heavy weight.

The backport of the concurrency library for Java 1.4 uses synchronization however it doesn't perform any where near as well.

Unsafe gives direct access to the Compare-and-Swap instructions of the CPU.

Comment: Do you think it exposes too much details about low level things?

Comment: @Clark, I think Unsafe is not needed in 99% of cases and you should use the classes which utilise the Unsafe class instead. Generally, it only useful to help you understand how using classes work.  In rare occasions, using Unsafe is the only way. ;)

Comment: /@Peter Maybe using multi thread itself is already pushing the language like java to its limit. Perhaps it is too hard to abstract all the functions needed for multi thread in some general utility classes.

Comment: @Clark, Multi-threading is built into Java and the concurrency library has been integrated since 2004. I certainly don't consider it pushing Java to the limit.  BTW You might like to have a look at the Unsafe class ;) http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html

Comment: /@Peter I looked. And no suprise, full of native methods. compareAndSwapObject compareAndSwapInt compareAndSwapLong , How are they different in CPU instructions. If one day CPU changes its behavior of multi-thread, java will also change the APIs I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of that the Programmers of the Atomics classes know what they do so they use the low level methodes for better performance.

Synchronize is a really heavy tool when doing multithreaded operations. Its way to powerful/blooted for simple locking/mutual exclusion.